# Interpreting Mathematica's expression for a function domain

Tags: functions

When I study the domain my function `f`:

```
f[x_] := 2/(Cos[x]^2) + 1/Log[Sin[x]]
FunctionDomain[f[x], x, Reals]
```

I receive the following answer.

> ```
> 1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers && 
> C[1] ∈ Integers && (2 π C[1] < x < 1/2 (π + 4 π C[1]) || 
> 1/2 (π + 4 π C[1]) < x < π + 2 π C[1])
> ```

I find it difficult to interpret the beginning of the answer:

> ```
> 1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers
> ```

Please explain this part. For the rest, I'm ok.

Comment: @Bendesarts If `x` had the value of  \[Pi]/2 the expression 1/2 + x/\[Pi] would evaluate to 1, an integer. The expression says that it is prohibited for 1/2 + x/\[Pi]  to evaluate to be an integer or you will be outside the function domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since your f[x] is a sum of two functions, why not try them separately?

```
FunctionDomain[2/(Cos[x]^2), x, Reals]

1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers
```

This is saying that values of x for which the denominator is zero are forbidden. The other half is

```
FunctionDomain[1/Log[Sin[x]], x, Reals]
```

which gives the rest.